# How does class know which implementation of an interface to take?

Tags: kotlin

I have a class with a function like so:

```kotlin
@Component
class UpdateService(
  private val storeGateway: UpdateStoreGateway,
  private val loadGateway: UpdateLoadGateway,
  private val updateNotify: UpdateNotify,
) : UpdateStorage {

override fun delete(key: UpdateKey) {
    if (loadGateway.loadByKey(key) != null) 
      storeGateway.delete(key)
      updateNotify.deleted()
    } 
  }
}
```

UpdateStoreGateway, UpdateLoadGateway and UpdateNotify are Interfaces. Since I'm new to Kotlin I can't quite grasp how the method `override fun delete(key: UpdateKey)` knows which implementation of the methods to take since there is no mention of the implementation class.

Comment: That's the whole point of interfaces. Whoever wrote the code decided that `delete` should _not_ know which implementation of those interfaces is used. If you want to know which implementation will actually be used when the code is run, put a breakpoint in `loadGateway.loadByKey`, and use your debugger to step into it.

Comment: Also, read about the dependency injection. Well designed software components do not create their dependencies (other services) by themselves, but expect that these dependencies will be provided to them. One of features of Spring is a dependency injection container, so you need to read its documentation to understand how these `UpdateStoreGateway`, etc. are created.

Comment: @Sweeper I see, so does the implementation depend on the parameter then? And if I were to write an implementation of an interface, how does the method know in its runtime, whether or not to jump to that implementation or not? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @inconnu this is all handled by spring based on the configuration the programmer provided, have a look at https://www.baeldung.com/inversion-control-and-dependency-injection-in-spring for a spring specific intro. But it sounds to me like you are missing knowledge about inversion of control/dependency injection, you can read the linked martin fowler articles in the conclusion of that link, or just use your favourite search engine to search either term which will give you thousands of articles explaining the principles.

Answer (score 1):

It's implementing all three!

An interface requires that all implementing clases must provide method(s) with the required signature(s).  (That is: having the required name, and taking the required parameter type(s).)  But there are no restrictions on *where* that method is defined: it could be in the implementing class, or inherited from a superclass.  And similarly, there are no restrictions on a method implementing more than one interface, if the signature matches.

All that matters is that users of the class know they can call the method(s) specified in all implemented interfaces; they shouldn't know or care about the details.